# Fabric.js - I have a bug: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, line, draw

I can't figure out the bug I have in my code.  So this fabric is drawing a line.  Then when I double click the line, I want control red "control points" to appear on each end of the line so I can then click and resize the line if I want (that code is not included yet).

Here is the code.

I'm getting this error.  It takes place on line 101 in the function updateNewLineCoordinates where it says: if(obj.id==='added-line') {

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at i.updateNewLineCoordinates

```
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    width: window.innerWidth, 
    height: window.innerHeight
});
    
let addingLineBtn = document.getElementById('adding-line-btn'); 
let addingLineBtnClicked = false;

addingLineBtn.addEventListener('click', activateAddingLine); 

function activateAddingLine() {
    if(addingLineBtnClicked===false) { 
        addingLineBtnClicked = true;
        canvas.on('mouse:down', startAddingLine); 
        canvas.on('mouse:move', startDrawingLine);
        canvas.on('mouse:up', stopDrawingLine);

        canvas.selection = false;  
        canvas.hoverCursor = 'auto';  
    
        objectSelectability('added-line', false);
    }    
}

let line; 
let mouseDown = false; 

function startAddingLine(o) {
    mouseDown = true;
    let pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    
    line = new fabric.Line([pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y], {
            id: 'added-line',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            selectable: false   
        });  
        
        canvas.add(line); 
        canvas.requestRenderAll(); 
}

function startDrawingLine(o) {
    if(mouseDown===true) {
        let pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e); 

        line.set({
            x2: pointer.x,
            y2: pointer.y
        });

        canvas.requestRenderAll(); 
    }
}

function stopDrawingLine() {
    line.setCoords();  
    mouseDown = false; 
}

let deactivateAddingShapeBtn = document.getElementById('deactivate-adding-shape-btn');

deactivateAddingShapeBtn.addEventListener('click', deactivateAddingShape)

function deactivateAddingShape(){
    canvas.off('mouse:down', startAddingLine); 
    canvas.off('mouse:move', startDrawingLine);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', stopDrawingLine);

    objectSelectability('added-line', true);

    canvas.hoverCursor = 'all-scroll';  
    addingLineBtnClicked = false;  
}

function objectSelectability(id,value) {
    canvas.getObjects().forEach(o => {  
        if(o.id===id) {                 
            o.set({                     
            })
        }
    });
}

canvas.on({  // this is so that when you move the line, the dblclick circles on the ends move with it.
    'object:moved': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'selection:created': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'selection:updated': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'mouse:dblclick': addingControlPoints
});

let newLineCoords = {};

function updateNewLineCoordinates(o) {  
    newLineCoords = {};
    
    let obj = o.target;

    if(obj.id==='added-line') {
        let centerX = obj.getCenterPoint().x; 
        let centerY = obj.getCenterPoint().y; 

        let x1offset = obj.calcLinePoints().x1;  
        let y1offset = obj.calcLinePoints().y1;
        let x2offset = obj.calcLinePoints().x2;
        let y2offset = obj.calcLinePoints().y2;

        newLineCoords = {  
            x1: centerX+x1offset,
            y1: centerY+y1offset,
            x2: centerX+x2offset,
            y2: centerY+y2offset
        }
    }
}

function addingControlPoints(o) {
    let obj = o.target;

    if(!obj) {  
        return;
    }
    else {
        if(obj.id==='added-line') {  
            let pointer1 = new fabric.Circle({  
                radius: obj.strokeWidth*3,
                fill: 'red', 
                opacity: 0.5,
                top: newLineCoords.y1,
                left: newLineCoords.x1,
                originX: 'center',  
                originY: 'center'
            });
        
            let pointer2 = new fabric.Circle({  
                radius: obj.strokeWidth*3,
                fill: 'red', 
                opacity: 0.5,
                top: obj.y2,
                left: obj.x2,
                originX: 'center',  
                originY: 'center'
            });
        
            canvas.add(pointer1,pointer2);
            canvas.requestRenderAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says to me that at least one of the `object:moved`, `selection:created` or `selection:updated` events does not have a `target` property

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  They all point to the function directly underneath that section of code.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the `.on()` method so it's hard to find details but the general gist of it seems to be that when any of those three event types occur, it calls your function. At least one of those calls is providing an argument `o` that does not have a `target` property. Do some debugging to see which one it is and what properties it _does_ have... `console.log("updateNewLineCoordinates", o);`